# Skipping iteration from Proc

Tags: ruby, iteration, metaprogramming, proc

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a `Proc` for skipping iteration in Ruby?

I wrote some piece of code

```
def validation i
  pr = Proc.new do |i|
    if i < 3
      next
    end
  end
  pr.call(i)
end

(1..5).each do |i|
  validation i
  puts "#{i} is bigger than 3"
end
```

and I expected something like this as result:

```
3 is bigger than 3
4 is bigger than 3
5 is bigger than 3
```

but instead I got:

```
1 is bigger than 3
2 is bigger than 3
3 is bigger than 3
4 is bigger than 3
5 is bigger than 3
```

So is it possible to use somehow `next` in `Proc` for skipping from outer iteration or there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `next` in your `validation` method because the loop is external. What you can do is use `next` within your `(1..5).each` loop that's dependent on a call to `validation`. The following code produces your desired result.

**Edit** - The code has been refactored to make appropriate use of `Proc`.

```
pr = Proc.new {|i| i < 3}

(1..5).each do |i|
  next if pr.call(i)
  puts "#{i} is bigger than 3"
end
```

Comment: Does it make sense to create a new `Proc` each time `validation` is called? You could define it separately @pr = `Proc...`.  Also `validate` returns `nil` when `i >= 3`, which is OK, but wouldn't it make more sense for the proc (and therefore `validate`) to just return `i<3` (i.e., `true` or `false`?

Comment: @Cary You are very much correct. My code (and the original) isn't making good (or any, really) use of the `Proc` function by instantiating `pr` repeatedly. As you pointed out, it would be more appropriate to move this outside of the function. Please see my edit, I've also included the `i < 3` refactor.

Comment: I think as calling next from Proc is impossible, using Proc in this situation no make sense at all. It's better to replace validation Proc with an ordinary method.